# Which Active record association should I use

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using rails 5.1.4 , so I have a table USER within I store all the users, then a user can send friend request to other users,  and I want to store that request into other table named FRIEND, like user_1 ( who send the request) -  user_2 (who is requested for)  , but you will understand that those two user (user_1, user_2) are coming from USER table.

It means: first I have this table Users which contains all the users. And what I want to say is that any user in this table user can be friend with any other user from the same table user.

Comment: You need to learn how to use whatever database you're working with first. This is a very basic step.

Comment: OK I understand what you mean.  But I asked for to know if I create a friend table how to specify  the relation has and belongs to between MODELS, wich one of those has two columns getting there values from the same table.

Comment: Maybe I didn't ask my question correctly because I'm trying to speak English.  but I'm asking about relation between model,  not about database it self. It's my first time to try a framework.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain what your asking in your question but it sounds like what you're looking to do is to have a table called Users and another table called Friends and to be able to store a value for the friend request.  I believe what you want to look into is a "has_many :through association" using a "join table".  Check out this video it walks you through it http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/what-is-a-has_many-through-association-in-ruby-on-rails-treehouse-quick-tip

here's more info on the Active Record association http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

**EDIT:**
Based on your below post what you want to do is just a simple has_many association.  In your User model add `has_many :friends, dependent: :destroy` and in your Friend model add `belongs_to :users` now go to your routes file and make friends a nested route of user by doing

```
  # nested routes for users
  resources :users do
    resources :friends
  end
```

in your friends table make sure you add a foreign key for users lik ethis in the migration       `t.references :user, foreign_key: true`

now in your friends_controller you need to update the actions like this.  Replace the example "patent" with your "friend" object.

```
class PatentsController < ApplicationController

  # first loads @user and then @patent for the below actions.
  before_action :set_user, only: [:index, :show, :new, :edit, :create, :update]
  before_action :set_patent, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /patents
  # GET /patents.json
  def index
    @patents = @user.patents
  end

  # GET /patents/1
  # GET /patents/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /patents/new
  def new
    @patent = @user.patents.new
  end

  # GET /patents/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /patents
  # POST /patents.json
  def create
    @patent = @user.patents.new(patent_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @patent.save
        format.html { redirect_to user_patents_path(@patent.user), notice: 'Patent was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @patent }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @patent.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /patents/1
  # PATCH/PUT /patents/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @patent.update(patent_params)
        format.html { redirect_to user_patents_path(@patent.user), notice: 'Patent was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @patent }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @patent.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /patents/1
  # DELETE /patents/1.json
  def destroy
    @patent.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to user_url(@user), notice: 'Patent was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  #######################
  # private methods
  #######################
  private

    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    end

    def set_patent
      @patent = Patent.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def patent_params
      params.require(:patent).permit(:patent_title, :patent_office, :patent_number, :patent_status, :patent_date, :patent_description, :user_id)
    end
end
```

Comment: OK look!, first I have a table Users wich contain all the users.  And what I want to say is that any user in this table can be friend with any other user from this table. You see what I mean?

Comment: see the updated answer, let me know if you get stuck.  also here a link to what you need to do https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1rlz081lrnU and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4QJSPWQlcaQ

Comment: My friend table is supposed to store something like this:

User1 User2 (TRUE if User2 accept the friend request,  else FALSE).
User1 is current_user
User2 is the one who the request is concern .

And both its coming from user table. 
Is that make sense to specify in the migration createfriend two columns  wich references the same model like this:

t.references :user,  .... For User1
t.teferences :user, ... For User2